# Swift reset constraint before going to next VC

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

In VC1 I am hiding an UIView by:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
            self.FilterContainer.alpha = 0
            self.TableConstraint.constant = -self.FilterContainer.bounds.height
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
```

If I then press my button and go to the second VC via my segue and then back again to VC1 my UIView is still hidden.

How can I make sure its visible once going back again?

I have tried: `viewDidAppear()` which kinda works.. Only problem is that you will see it jump down, I would like it to be at the right position form start.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should get rid of completion block of animation and reset view state just after animation is finished

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
        self.FilterContainer.alpha = 0
        self.TableConstraint.constant = -self.FilterContainer.bounds.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: { _ in

        self.FilterContainer.alpha = 1.00
        self.TableConstraint.constant = 0 // or whatever its initial value is
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```

Comment: viewWillAppear fixed it